# Error sintaxis en Python 3 (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, sintaxis

Estoy utilizando la función replace para limpiar una columna de un dataset. En este caso pongo los precios al formato "americano" para tenerlos todos en este mismo formato.
No obstante me da un error y no entiendo porque?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otras columnas he utlizado la función replace de la misma manera con otros datos y ha funcionado.
Muchas gracias de antemano!!!
Saludos.

Comment: Tienes un error de tipeo en el `60,98` deberia ser `"asd": 'asd'` y no `"asd", 'asd'`

Comment: Hola braver, en efecto, tambien tenia otro en 37,45. Muchas gracias!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hola Carlos, por favor edita tu pregunta y añada el código en formato de texto en lugar de una imagen. De esa formas te podremos ayudar mejor y será más sencillo que alguien encuentre tu duda con el buscador.